# How to write a java tree Structure and Serializer/Deserializer to Json

Tags: java, json, serialization, tree

I use spring framework.

I want to implements Java tree structure and `Serializer/Deserializer` to `JSON`.

like below `JSON`,

```
 [  
        {"id":"1","pid":"0","name":"n1", "chindren":[  
            {"id":"4","pid":"1","name":"n4", "chindren":[  
                {"id":"7","pid":"4","name":"n7", "chindren":[  
                    {"id":"15","pid":"7","name":"n15"}

                ]},  
                {"id":"8","pid":"4","name":"n8"},  
                {"id":"9","pid":"4","name":"n9"},  
                {"id":"10","pid":"4","name":"n10"}  
            ]},  
            {"id":"5","pid":"1","name":"n5","chindren":[  
                {"id":"19","pid":"5","name":"n19"},  
                {"id":"20","pid":"5","name":"n20"}  
            ]}  
        ]},  
        {"id":"2","pid":"0","name":"n2","chindren":[  
            {"id":"13","pid":"2","name":"n13"}

        ]},  
        {"id":"3","pid":"0","name":"n3","chindren":[  
            {"id":"11","pid":"3","name":"n11"},  
            {"id":"12","pid":"3","name":"n12"}  
        ]}  
    ]
```

How to convert above JSON tree to a Java class and `Serializer/Deserializer` to JSON

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use jackson libs with your spring frame work to convert json to java classes and vice versa.
For more information about jackson [see this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html)

To generate java pojo classes use this online tool [click here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

hope it will help you.

Comment: sorry, can you give me the whole example contains the **TreeNode.class**  and **Serializer/Deserializer**

Answer (score 1):

Go through this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) if you want to use Jackson for converting Java objects to / from JSON.

As far as your JSON is concerned, I think the POJO you need should look something like this.

```
public class Model {

    private String id;
    private String pid;
    private String name;
    private List<Model> children; // I assumed you meant children

    // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Using Jackson, you can deserialize JSONs as follows (I'm assuming it is in a JSON file):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Model> listModel = objectMapper.readValue(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/newjson.json"), new TypeReference<List<Model>>() {
});
```

I used Jackson in the above example because that is what I extensively use. You could use GSON if you want.

Maven dependency for Jackson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

It is better if you read up a bit on these topics.

Answer (score 0):

There are new useful tools like swagger for this issue. http://swagger.io/ you can check this link out. It is a nice tool for generating apis for popular frameworks. All you need to do is writing the interfaces in yaml format end using the swagger editor tool by specifying your frameworks (in your case its spring and java) It will generate all the apis and model objects. Then you can use Gson for serializing those auto-generated interfaces.