# Jackson JSON array accessing

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have a Json file like this:

```
[{
    dname: "xxxx",
    dage: "24"
}, {
    dname: "yyyy",
    dage: "26"
}]
```

**Target:**

1. I want to access them as an array
2. Search through the names in the JSON file to look for a particular name
3. Same for age.

## **What I did:**

file name : DtExtract.java

```
 public class DtExtract{

 public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

 private Dtmain[] dtmain =mapper.readValue(new File("file location"),     TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructArrayType(D tmain.class));


 public DtExtract() throws IOException{}
 public String getname(int i) throws IOException { String strname =      dtmain[i].getjname(); return strname;}

 public String getage(int i) throws IOException { String strage = dtmain[i].getjage(); return strage;}

}
class Dtmain {

private String dname;

private String dage;

public Dtmain(){}

public String getjname(){return dname;}

public String getjage(){return dage;}

public void setjname(String dname){ this.dname=dname;}

public void setjage(String dage){ this.dage=dage;}

public String toString(){ return "Student [ name" + dname +", age " +dage +"]";
}
```

============================

file name: Myclass.java

```
 public class Myclass{

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

 DtExtract dtextract= new DtExtract();

 for(int i=0; i< 2; i++)

 {

 if (dtextract.getname(i).equals("xxxx")) {System.out.print("Name matches");}

 if (dtextract.getage(i).equals("24")) {System.out.print("Age matches");}

 }
 }
 }
```

=============================

This is the abstract of a code that I have, but **my question is**:

1. Does this for loop is really accessing the JSON array elements?
2. Is there any other faster way to do this JSON parsing and comparison?

Comment: Are you comparing the JSON data to avoid duplicates?

Comment: No ... based on the match I'll execute some other tasks. This is just an abstract of the code.

Comment: Looking for a faster and easy way to search through the json array which I have presented above the code.

Comment: see this hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654814/how-to-write-a-java-tree-structure-and-serializer-deserializer-to-json/38654973#38654973

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows. You need to call both methods from `main` method

Please note that I have added two methods to process the array. `processJsonArrayJava8` will be faster compared to `processJsonArrayJava7`.

```
public List<Dtmain> readFromJson()
            throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException    {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    TypeReference<List<Dtmain>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<Dtmain>>() {};
    List<Dtmain> jsonList = mapper.readValue(
            "[{\"dname\": \"xxxx\",\"dage\": \"24\" },{\"dname\": \"yyyy\",\"dage\": \"26\" }]",
            mapType);

    return jsonList;

}

public void processJsonArrayJava7(List<Dtmain> jsonList) {

    for(Dtmain obj : jsonList) {
        //  do what ever you want with obj
    }

}

public void processJsonArrayJava8(List<Dtmain> jsonList) {

    jsonList.parallelStream().forEach(obj->{
     //do what ever you want with obj
    });

}
```

Please also give better names to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SayHi {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<List<Person>> maptype = new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {};
        List<Person> jsonTopersonList=mapper.readValue(new File("JSON_file_location"), maptype);
        for(int i=0; i<jsonTopersonList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Name"+i+":"+jsonTopersonList.get(i).dname);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<jsonTopersonList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Age"+i+":"+jsonTopersonList.get(i).dage);
        }

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
 public class Person {
    public String dname;
    public int dage;
    public Person() {
    }
    public Person(String dname,
                  int dage) {
        this.dname = dname;
        this.dage = dage;
     }
    public String toString() {
         return "[" + dname + " " + dage +"]";
    }
 }
```

I came up with this one to deserialize that json data.